# Mongodb C# GridFS Projection on field in MetaData

Tags: c#, mongodb, gridfs

I want to make a Projection on an field in the metadata of the GridFS.

First I do like this:

```
        var options = new GridFSFindOptions
    {
        AllowDiskUse = true
    };
    var filterDefinition = FilterDefinition<GridFSFileInfo>.Empty;
    using var cursor = _reportArchiveBucket.Find(filterDefinition, options);
    var retVal = new List<string>();
    foreach (var fileInfo in cursor.ToEnumerable())
    {
        fileInfo.Metadata.TryGetValue("DeviceType", out var deviceType);
        if(deviceType != null) retVal.Add(deviceType.AsString);
    }
    return retVal;
```

But is their a better way? The Problem that the GRidFSBucket did not supoort projection